# R - Matching the Street Name with Postcode from a different df and applying the results to new column

Tags: r

I am trying to use the street name in df1 to locate a postcode in a sdf2. df2 contains the same street names as the df1 but the street may be linked with several postcodes (the same street name be be found in several cities). To find the postcode where there are multiple values returned I need to take the most common result. Once I have found the postcode and I need to add it to a new column in df1 in the same row as the street name. df1 contains 500,000 rows and df2 contains 900,000+ rows

```
head(AllNICrimeData, 10)
 Month Longitude Latitude             Location            Crime.type
1  2015-01 -6.003289 54.55165      SALISBURY PLACE Anti-social behaviour
2  2015-01 -5.707979 54.59231                      Anti-social behaviour
3  2015-01 -5.815976 54.73161        MILEBUSH PARK Anti-social behaviour
4  2015-01 -6.393411 54.19788 COLLEGE SQUARE NORTH Anti-social behaviour
5  2015-01 -6.251798 54.85970         STAFFA DRIVE Anti-social behaviour
6  2015-01 -7.206893 54.62265    KILLYCLOGHER ROAD Anti-social behaviour
7  2015-01 -5.915793 54.59242      RAVENHILL REACH Anti-social behaviour
8  2015-01 -5.535389 54.48792                      Anti-social behaviour
9  2015-01 -7.322812 54.99940   GREAT JAMES STREET Anti-social behaviour
10 2015-01 -5.954670 54.61568         JAMAICA ROAD Anti-social behaviour

head(CleanNIPostcodeData[, 6:14],)
Number Primary_Thorfare Alt_Thorfare Secondary_Thorfare  Locality          
Townland        Town County Postcode
1    134   WHITEPARK ROAD         <NA>               <NA> BALLINTOY 
BALLINTOY DEMESNE BALLYCASTLE ANTRIM  BT546ND
2     27  PRINCESS STREET         <NA>               <NA>      <NA>         
PORT RUSH    PORTRUSH ANTRIM  BT568AX
3   <NA>   COVEHILL COURT         <NA>               <NA>      <NA>        
GLENAMANUS    PORTRUSH ANTRIM  BT568GL
4    271     OLDPARK ROAD         <NA>               <NA>      <NA>        
TOWN PARKS     BELFAST ANTRIM  BT146QR
5     2A    RAMORE STREET         <NA>               <NA>      <NA>         
PORT RUSH    PORTRUSH ANTRIM  BT568BD
6     52  EGLINTON STREET         <NA>               <NA>      <NA>         
PORT RUSH    PORTRUSH ANTRIM  BT568DY
```

What I need to achieve is to find the post frequent postcode in df2 associated with a street in df1 and add the postcode to a new column in the same row as the street in df 1. The example below shows where a location is associated with multiple postcodes:

```
table(CleanNIPostcodeData$Postcode[AllNICrimeData$Location[3] == CleanNIPostcodeData$Primary_Thorfare])
BT387PU BT387QR 
 22      64
```

I have been able to identify how to get the most frequent postcode, when more than one postcode is associated with a location,  but am not able to create the new column with the postcode for all streets.

```
names(which.max(table(CleanNIPostcodeData$Postcode[AllNICrimeData$Location[3] == CleanNIPostcodeData$Primary_Thorfare])))
```

In the example above I find the most recurring postcode for the 3rd street name in df1. the output is the postcode "BT387QR"

How do I get my code above to apply to the entire column and create and populate a new postcode column in df1

The expected output is a new column in df1 with the matching postcode for the street name.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @notAprogrammer You have added data but in that data you have not shown  `BT387QR` entry in `CleanNIPostcodeData`. Can you please paste that row as well?

Comment: @MKR The postcode can be located anywhere in the postcode column of df2. I'm using the street name to find the postcode as the street name is in both df 1 and df 2

Comment: @notAprogrammer That means you are comparing `Location` with `Primary_Thorfare` to find the related records. A `left_join` can help you in that case.

Comment: @notAprogrammer I have modified your data to introduce at least one  matching `Postcode`. You can try answer and provide feedback. Are you looking for something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps all you need is to use `dplyr::left_join` to join both data.frames and get the `Postcode`

The below result is on modified data to exhibit logic.

```
library(dplyr)
AllNICrimeData %>% left_join(select(CleanNIPostcodeData, Primary_Thorfare,Postcode) , 
by=c("Location" = "Primary_Thorfare"))


#        Month Longitude Latitude             Location            Crime.type Postcode
#   1  2015-01 -6.003289 54.55165      SALISBURY PLACE Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   2  2015-01 -5.707979 54.59231                 <NA> Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   3  2015-01 -5.815976 54.73161        MILEBUSH PARK Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   4  2015-01 -6.393411 54.19788 COLLEGE SQUARE NORTH Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   5  2015-01 -6.251798 54.85970         STAFFA DRIVE Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   6  2015-01 -7.206893 54.62265    KILLYCLOGHER ROAD Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   7  2015-01 -5.915793 54.59242      RAVENHILL REACH Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   8  2015-01 -5.535389 54.48792                 <NA> Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   9  2015-01 -7.322812 54.99940   GREAT JAMES STREET Anti-social behaviour     <NA>
#   10 2015-01 -5.954670 54.61568         JAMAICA ROAD Anti-social behaviour  BT568DY
```

If I have to keep `Postcode` search logic as mentioned by OP then solution could be written as:

```
AllNICrimeData$newcol <- mapply(function(x)names(which.max(table(CleanNIPostcodeData$Postcode[x == CleanNIPostcodeData$Primary_Thorfare]))),
AllNICrimeData$Location)
```

**Data:**

```
AllNICrimeData <- read.table(text = 
"Month Longitude Latitude             Location            Crime.type
1  2015-01 -6.003289 54.55165     ' SALISBURY PLACE' 'Anti-social behaviour'
2  2015-01 -5.707979 54.59231                   NA   'Anti-social behaviour'
3  2015-01 -5.815976 54.73161        'MILEBUSH PARK' 'Anti-social behaviour'
4  2015-01 -6.393411 54.19788 'COLLEGE SQUARE NORTH' 'Anti-social behaviour'
5  2015-01 -6.251798 54.85970         'STAFFA DRIVE' 'Anti-social behaviour'
6  2015-01 -7.206893 54.62265    'KILLYCLOGHER ROAD' 'Anti-social behaviour'
7  2015-01 -5.915793 54.59242      'RAVENHILL REACH' 'Anti-social behaviour'
8  2015-01 -5.535389 54.48792                   NA   'Anti-social behaviour'
9  2015-01 -7.322812 54.99940   'GREAT JAMES STREET' 'Anti-social behaviour'
10 2015-01 -5.954670 54.61568         'JAMAICA ROAD' 'Anti-social behaviour'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



CleanNIPostcodeData <- read.table(text = 
"Number Primary_Thorfare    Alt_Thorfare Secondary_Thorfare  Locality  Townland               Town     County  Postcode
1    134   'WHITEPARK ROAD'         <NA>               <NA> BALLINTOY 'BALLINTOY DEMESNE' BALLYCASTLE    ANTRIM  BT546ND
2     27  'PRINCESS STREET'         <NA>               <NA>      <NA> 'PORT RUSH'            PORTRUSH    ANTRIM  BT568AX
3   <NA>   'COVEHILL COURT'         <NA>               <NA>      <NA> GLENAMANUS           PORTRUSH    ANTRIM  BT568GL
4    271     'OLDPARK ROAD'         <NA>               <NA>      <NA> 'TOWN PARKS'            BELFAST    ANTRIM  BT146QR
5     2A    'RAMORE STREET'         <NA>               <NA>      <NA> 'PORT RUSH'            PORTRUSH    ANTRIM  BT568BD
6     52  'JAMAICA ROAD'         <NA>               <NA>      <NA> 'PORT RUSH'            PORTRUSH    ANTRIM  BT568DY",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried a left_join but I don't think that addresses the problem of a street having matches with multiple postcodes, for example Main street might appear in different towns resulting in different postcodes. In this instance I need to identify the most frequent postcode and use that value for all locations = Main Street

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I will try now and hopefully the mapply will provide the results I need.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It took some time to work but created a list in the new postcode column in df 1. I have marked as answered